# Table column sorting based on NULL Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to sort column2 based on Column1 values. I want split column1 data based on NULL value. The final query result will be displayed on evaluating the values in the column1

```
   Column1    Column2 
    NULL         100
    NULL          60
    NULL          90
    10            22
    20            40
    05            35
    15            20
    40            10
    30            25
    20            30

Would become:

   Column1     Column2 
    20            40
    05            35
    20            30
    30            25
    10            22
    15            20
    40            10
    NULL         100
    NULL          90
    NULL          60

Thanks
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use case in your `order by` clause like this:

```
Select * from t
Order by case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end, column2 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a case in your order by

```
ORDER BY case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end, column2 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 1 AS Grp, column2
FROM T 
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Grp, column2 
FROM T 
WHERE column1 IS NULL
ORDER BY Grp, column2;
```

This an alternative to GurV's approach, where this can actually benefit from indexes.

GurV's approach:

[image]

Union approach:

[image]